# How to style elements outside root node

Tags: reactjs

I have some simple components that are rendering with some gaps on sides. To remove these gaps I added body styles into index.htm

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>React Development</title>
<style> body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; } </style>
</head>
```

This is similar like we have on default example in create-react-app. Here is the app code.

```
const Header = () => <div style={headerStyle}>Discover unlimited possibilities</div>;
class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Is it possible to do it this way? I saw some people style with plain javascript, example:

```
document.body.style.margin = "0px";
```

Comment: Yes using vanilla js to update styles is a fine way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Can I add this vanilla into actual app.js where I have components? Or add it into the index.htm between <script></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should work fine in style tag. You can even create an App.css file and import it in your App component code with the following in it

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do vanilla js in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to style the body.

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.margin = "0px";
}
```

Comment: Shall I put it inside the main component App?

Comment: @kilogram Yep! You can put that in whatever component you want.